# find and replace with sed in folder recursively with slash in find and replace string

Tags: sed

I want to replace `/var/www` with `/home/lokesh/www` using the sed command:

```
sed -i 's/\//var\//www/\//home\//lokesh\//www/g' lks.php
```

but this gives an error:

```
sed: couldn't open file ww/\//home\//lokesh\//www/g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"? Your example appears to change only one file. Do you want to apply this to all files under the current directory? Or perhaps all PHP files? If so, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45141398/edit) and include your preferred shell and operating system, as tools may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use forward slashes as a delimited for sed's substitution command, then you need to escape backslashes within the pattern or replacement:

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/www\//\/home\/lokesh\/www\//g' lks.php
```

But Sed's substitution command can use any character as a delimiter. The same command might be easier to read as:

```
sed -i 's:/var/www/:/home/lokesh/www/:g' lks.php
```

Common alternatives to a slash include colon (`:`), comma (`,`) and vertical-bar (`|`), but any character will do. From the sed man page:

> *Any character other than backslash or newline can be used instead of a slash to delimit the RE and the replacement.*